# place '-' after every four charecters while adding Credit card

Tags: ios4, uitextfield

hi friends i want to add '-' symbol while user adding credit card number through UItextField,we need to write code in **shouldChangeCharactersInRange** method
Can any one suggest me how write code for this

Answer (score 0):

You can make different UITextFields.
When the user enters 4 digits into a textfield, you can use the shouldChangeCharactersInRange method to calculate if the maximum of 4 digits is reached (or passed).

When this occurs, you **resignFirstResponder** on the textfield and call **becomesFirstResponder** on the next textfield.